# Node js persistent job scheduler with database layer

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, scheduler, jobs

I have an express backend and I need to schedule jobs for months or even years ahead, but I couldn't find a persistent solution, I need the jobs to be there even if I change servers. I have seen agenda.js which has a persistent layer based on mongodb, I am using postgres and I don't want to use mongodb, any recommendations?

I searched but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/graphile/worker

Comment: Thank's for the recomendation, it really helped. you can post as an answer that I can upvote.

Comment: No, because software recommendations are off-topic and usually become outdated quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but there is no solution existing except Agenda and Bree for job persistance. And they use both Redis or MongoDB.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35357673)